# How do I distribute h:selectOneRadio's select items across the page?

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

All I need to is to spread dependent radio options like this:

```
<h:panelGroup id="part1">
  <!-- several radio options -->
</h:panelGroup>
<h:panelGroup id="part2">
  <!-- several radio options -->
</h:panelGroup>
```

Placing the above snippet inside `h:selectOneRadio` has no effect, whereas placing two `h:selectOneRadio`s inside each `h:panelGroup` makes selection independent. As far as I remember this is possible in plain html by using the same name for `input`s.

What are my chances in JSF2?

Comment: Use p:selectOneRadio with custom layout feature. http://www.primefaces.org/showcase-labs/ui/selectOneRadio.jsf

Afaik, h:selectOneRadio does not custom layout option. Only horizontal and vertical.

Comment: @CagatayCivici, thanks, can you post it as an answer so that I could accept it?